# Infinite fields of characteristic $p$

Tags: abstract-algebra

I need to find two infinite fields of characteristic $p$ which are not isomorphic.

Comment: Well, what is an example of such a field, first of all?

Comment: The duplicate question doesn't ask for two non-isomorphic examples, but the answers contain lots of them.